# get_option() is not working even db contains the corresponding option_name and option_value

Tags: options

First of all, this is not a plugin specific problem. I wonder why this might happen? I am using @bainternet's Tax Meta Class for saving Taxonomy Meta using the `options` table. I uploaded my contents from localhost (XAMPP Windows 5.5.19 environment ), I found my data in options table. Everything was working fine.

Now I uploaded my site to the server (Linux | PHP 5.2.17) and it's failing retrieving the data from the options table.

```
$type_icon_array = get_tax_meta( $type->term_id, 'offer_type_icon' );
var_dump( $type->term_id ); //showing the id nicely
var_dump( $type_icon_array ); //showing null
```

The function failed retrieving data. How the function is:

```
//get term meta field
  public function get_tax_meta($term_id,$key,$multi = false){
    $t_id = (is_object($term_id))? $term_id->term_id: $term_id;
    $m = get_option( 'tax_meta_'.$t_id);  
    if (isset($m[$key])){
      return $m[$key];
    }else{
      return '';
    }
  }
```

I bypass the Tax Meta functions, and tried the WP rudimentary:

```
$tst1 = get_option( 'tax_meta_6' );
var_dump($tst1); //showing null
```

As you can see the database has the value in `options` table:
[image: db has options value]

But you can see what happened:
[image: showing null]

I then uploaded one image (while I'm on the remote server) in Taxonomy ID #2, and you can see the image is showing there.

What could happen here, that the value is in db, but `get_option()` is not having that value? (But it's working while I'm updating the field in **that particular environment**) I even tried:

```
get_option( 'tax_meta_6', array() );
```

with no luck! :(

I know WordPress' minimum requirement is PHP 5.2.4, but can that missing dev. version cause such a massacre?

---

## Edit

I found a reason why this **COULD**/**MIGHT** happen: I checked both the local and server serialized data and found one little mismatch there, suppose my local data is:

```
a: 1: {
    s: 15: "offer_type_icon";
    a: 2: {
        s: 2: "id";
        s: 3: "428";
        s: 3: "url";
        s: 61: "http://localhost/example/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/image.png";
    }
}
```

When I'm uploading to the server replacing all the base URL, the sever data becomes:

```
a: 1: {
    s: 15: "offer_type_icon";
    a: 2: {
        s: 2: "id";
        s: 3: "428";
        s: 3: "url";
        s: 61: "http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/image.png";
    }
}
```

The URL is changing but the string count for the changed URL remains same as of localhost. But it should be `44` because the new base URL is 17 character less.

If this is the cause, how can I solve such WP migration while the db has serialized data with site URL?

## EDIT 2

**YES, this IS the reason.**

The serialized URL data is being changed but their string count isn't.

Comment: I found one script http://davidcoveney.com/575/php-serialization-fix-for-wordpress-migrations/ - till not tried, let's see it first. And another on github: https://github.com/Blogestudio/Fix-Serialization

Comment: I think you could post the reason of the problem and the possible solutions as an answer. ;)

Comment: The Only Issue i see here is that you uploaded the database after a string search and replace which is a big no no in WordPress world, because WordPress stores arrays as serialized data. always use serialized data safe search and replace.

Comment: @Bainternet Got your point. A big *no* *no* on search-replace while uploading database.

Comment: @MayeenulIslam YEP :)

Comment: @Bainternet I updated my post with your voice, and changed [my article](http://tuts.nanodesignsbd.com/wordpress-taxonomy-meta-complete-guide/#update-20150909) accordingly. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, at last found that, the serialized data, where there is a site_url exists, are causing the problem while I'm migrating the data from localhost to server replacing the local URL to server URL.

I found two solution, both are not tested yet:

- [PHP Serialization Fix for WordPress Migrations (& other applications like Expression Engine)](http://davidcoveney.com/575/php-serialization-fix-for-wordpress-migrations/) by *David Coveney*
- [Fix-Serialization](https://github.com/Blogestudio/Fix-Serialization) (Script to fix length attributes in serialized strings) - by *Pau Iglesias*

Need not to say that, **try them with your own risk**.

### EDIT

> BEFORE EVERYTHING
> **BACK UP** YOUR DATABASE FIRST

Okay, I found the first one only specific to `options` table and not much flexible and not reliable too (WTFLicensed :p ). So I went with the second one by *Pau Iglesias*.

I found it working just fine. But as I'm a Windows user, couldn't use shell script, so I forked his repo and made my own way using the same script:

- [**serialization-fixer**](https://github.com/mayeenulislam/serialization-fixer) - Raw PHP way - github

Using my one is a bit sever-specific. You will need to put your exported string-replaced `.sql` file into the **same** folder where the `serialization-fixer.php` is. Then you need to open the file and change line#21 with your `.sql` file's filename. After then you can simply run the file from your browser.

Thanks to *Pau Iglesias* for his nice scripts.