# Adding a meta box fields to child theme options page

Tags: functions, child-theme, theme-options

I created a custom options page for may theme using this code:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'jrl_add_admin_menu' );
function jrl_add_admin_menu()
{
    add_menu_page('Options', 'Options', 'manage_options', 'functions','custom_options','dashicons-welcome-learn-more');
}
function custom_options()
{
?>
    <div id="jrl-wrap">
    <div id="icon-tools" class="icon32"></div>
        <h1>Options</h1>
        <p>Add Informations.</p>
        <hr>
        <form method="post" action="options.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <?php wp_nonce_field('update-options') ?>
  <table class="widefat">
  <tr valign="">
  <th scope="row"><label for="myplugin_option_name">Title:</label></th>
  <td><input type="text" name="jrlname" size="45" value="<?php echo get_option('jrlname'); ?>" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr valign="">
  <th scope="row"><label for="myplugin_option_name">Title Abbreviation:</label></th>
  <td><input type="text" name="abr" size="45" value="<?php echo get_option('abr'); ?>" /></td>
  </tr>  <br>
  <tr valign="">
  <th scope="row"><label for="myplugin_option_name">Publisher:</label></th>
  <td><input type="text" name="pub" size="45" value="<?php echo get_option('pub'); ?>" /></td>
  </tr>
  </table><hr>
            <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Save Options"  /></p>
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update" />
            <input type="hidden" name="page_options" value="jrlname,abr,pub" />
        </form>
    </div>
<?php
}
function load_custom_wp_admin_style() {
    wp_register_style( 'custom_wp_admin_css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/functions/options.css', false, '1.0.0' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_wp_admin_css' );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_custom_wp_admin_style' );
```

I need to add a repeater field to this options page. I found a method to add meta box to custom taxonomy using this code from (https://github.com/bainternet/Tax-Meta-Class):

```
require_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/Tax-meta-class/Tax-meta-class.php' );
$rep = array(
   'id' => 'demo_meta_box',
   'title' => 'Demo Meta Box',
   'pages' => array('category'),
   'context' => 'normal',
   'fields' => array(),
   'local_images' => false,
   'use_with_theme' => true
);
$my_meta = new Tax_Meta_Class($rep);
$repeater_fields[] = $my_meta->addText('re_text_field_id',array('name'=> 'My Text '),true);
$repeater_fields[] = $my_meta->addTextarea('re_textarea_field_id',array('name'=> 'My Textarea '),true);
$repeater_fields[] = $my_meta->addCheckbox('re_checkbox_field_id',array('name'=> 'My Checkbox '),true);
$repeater_fields[] = $my_meta->addImage('image_field_id',array('name'=> 'My Image '),true);
 $my_meta->addRepeaterBlock('re_',array('inline' => true, 'name' => 'This is a Repeater Block','fields' => $repeater_fields));
$my_meta->Finish();
```

How can I use this last code to add the meta box to the options page & not to a taxonomy?
I tried to add the code to the first one changing :
`'pages' => array('category'),` to `'pages' => array('functions'),` where functions is the slug of my custom options page but nothing happened, no fields displayed in the options page. Am I missing something here? Any help please?

Comment: Just to let you know, Tax Meta Class by Bainternet has [issues](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/184850/22728) that you should aware of.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MayeenulIslam. I'll take a look. But do you have any alternative clean solution please?

Comment: scalable? no. I don't have any concrete solution right now for repeated fields. But I [wrote an article](http://tuts.nanodesignsbd.com/wordpress-taxonomy-meta-complete-guide/) in Bengali about how taxonomy meta works, with how to negotiate with the URL issues. You may not get help from the Bengali article, even with translator, but you can have a look at the code snippets there. But you have to build your own repeated fields, using jQuery.

Comment: take a look at this https://github.com/bainternet/Admin-Page-Class

Comment: @MayeenulIslam please get your facts right before notifying people about "bugs" or "issues".

Comment: @Bainternet thanks a lot. I tried your meta-tax-class code & it worked but with normal image field (not in repeaeter) I tried to use `$saved_data = met_tax_meta($term->ID,'image_field_id',true);
 echo '<img src="'.$saved_data['src'].'">';` to display the image but it didn't work. any suggestions please?

Comment: use `var_dump($saved_data )` to see how the data is stored and how to access it.